# 2's complement addition with ZF/Carry/Overflow

Tags: computer-architecture

> Consider addition of two numbers when CPU uses $2's$ complement form:
>   $$ 1\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 1\\0\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 1\ 0\ 0\\-------\\0\ 0\ 0\
>  0\ 1\ 1\ 1\ 1\\------- $$

$$Carry\ = 1,\
Overflow = 0, \  Zero Flag = 0$$

**My Reasoning:**

- Zero Flag isn't set because the *result isn't zero*
- Overflow isn't set because *Carry in = Carry out*

**However, the answer says that Zero Flag is set $(ZF = 1)$, Am I going wrong ?**

---

Note:

- Got ZF/Carry/Overflow info from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10945166/what-is-the-diffrence-between-zero-flag-and-carry-flag)

Comment: Your question already includes a complete answer to the original problem but no question *about* this answer. Thus, only "yes/no" answers may remain, helping neither you nor future visitors. Please read related meta discussions [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/519/) and adjust your question accordingly, e.g. by formulating a specific question about a single element of your answer you are uncertain about. If you just want general feedback, you are welcome to visit us in [chat].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, the answer says that Zero Flag is set (ZF=1), Am I going
>   wrong ?

No, you are correct. If the result is not zero, and in this case it is not, the zero flag is not set.

Comment: Yeah, I too felt the same